# Can I Structure this Data in a More Efficient Way?

Tags: arrays, indexing, big-o

I'm implementing a list of `research_projects` with dynamic filtering. I have a bunch of tables in the database representing their many-to-many relationships with fields such as `principal investigator` and `funder`.

Because I want the filtering to be dynamic, I am pulling ALL of this data up front and storing it in the browser, then filtering that data with javascript.

Currently, the data I'm pulling has the following structure:

```
research_projects = 
{
    "RPGUID1":
    {
        "title":"blah",
        "summary":"balh",
        "description":"blah",
        etc...
    },
    "RPGUID2":
    {
        "title":"blah2",
        etc...
    },
    ...
}
principal_investigators = 
{
    "12345":
    {
        "name":"John D",
        "slug":"john-d",
        "research_projects":["RPGUID2"]
    },
    ...
}
funders = 
{
    "aaaa":
    {
        "name":"funder A",
        "slug":"funder-a",
        "research_projects":["RPGUID1", "RPGUID2"]
    },
    ...
}
```

I chose this arrangement to avoid searching the main `research_projects` array in linear time.

While this structure is fine for filtering alone, it is rather inefficient for other features I want.

Below is a list of functions, along with their time-complexity in the current structure. I need to restructure this data in a way that optimizes for as many of these functions as possible:

1. get the `title` of a `research_project` given its `id`

   - O(1)
2. get all `research_projects` of a given `funder`

   - O(1) lookup, linear in the size of `funder[research_projects]`
3. get all `funder`s of a given `research_project`

   - linear in the size of `funders` **and** `funders[research_projects]`
4. get the `slug` of a `funder` given its `id`

   - O(1)
5. get the `id` of a `funder` given its `slug`

   - linear in the size of `funders`

All of these functions are required to run *multiple times* whenever the user selects a new filter, which is why I'm looking into alternative solutions.

Thanks

Comment: Well, one of the biggest advantages of databases are indexes and other efficient algorithms (e.g. using hashing etc.) Once you just load all the data you have to reimplement all of them to obtain very good performances... But this means increasing the memory footprint... how much data are you handling? This is important to decide how to handle your data structures...